# update SSL configurations using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, ssl, tls1.2

I added SSL certifcate using the below:-

```
 New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding -WebAppName $app.SiteName -Thumbprint $new_thumbprint -Name $ssl_binding.Name -ResourceGroupName $app.ResourceGroup
```

but i was wondering if:-
Is it possible to update SSL configuration using powershell
[image: update SSL Configuration]

What I am trying to do is:-
1) Change 'https only' to 'ON' 
2) Minimum TLS version to '1.2'

using PS

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure it out.

```
# SET staging
$PropertiesObject = @{
    'httpsOnly' = 'true';
    'minTlsVersion' = '1.2'

}
Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName RG-AUTHSERVER -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots -ResourceName "authserver-web/staging" -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 -Force
# SET staging
$PropertiesObject = @{
    'minTlsVersion' = '1.2'

}
Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName RG-AUTHSERVER -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config -ResourceName "authserver-web/staging/web" -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 -Force
```